# I2C slave implementation - clock frequency?

Tags: i2c, slave

I want to implement a I2C SLAVE in an FPGA, just for learning purposes. I read in the I2C specification that for the FAST mode there is a timing parameter tPS = 50ns (max) which means "pulse width of spikes that must be suppressed by the input filter". Should this be a digital filter inside the slave? If yes, does that mean my slave must have a maximum clock period of 25ns (or something)?

Another question would be: is there a (robust) way of implementing this slave using the SCL line as the only clock? Or a faster second clock is needed (and in this case I would treat the SCL line as "data")? If so, how do I calculate the minimum frequency of this other clock?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I2C specifies only few maximum frequencies (up to 100kHz, 400kHz, 1MHz, 3.4MHz). Some vendors enabled so called Ultra Speed mode (up to 5MHz). Here you can easily see that period of clock usually is higher than 200ns.

Comment: I didn't mean the SCL frequency... I meant the sampling clock frequency.